# How to use react-boostrap with next.js and React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap, next.js

My project is using react.js and next.js, I am trying to create a Carousel by using react-boostrap. But when i try this problem appear
I also have include next.config.js in my project

Here is the error ([the picture of the errror](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GMlGB.png)):
[image: error]

And this my code:

```js
import React from 'react'
import Bootstrap from 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
import Carousel from 'react-bootstrap/Carousel'
class ControlledCarousel extends React.Component {
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context)

    this.handleSelect = this.handleSelect.bind(this)

    this.state = {
      index: 0,
      direction: null
    }
  }

  handleSelect(selectedIndex, e) {
    this.setState({
      index: selectedIndex,
      direction: e.direction
    })
  }

  render() {
    const { index, direction } = this.state

    return (
      <div>
        <Carousel
          activeIndex={index}
          direction={direction}
          onSelect={this.handleSelect}
        >
          <Carousel.Item>
            <img
              className="d-block w-100"
              src="holder.js/800x400?text=First slide&bg=373940"
              alt="First slide"
            />
            <Carousel.Caption>
              <h3>First slide label</h3>
              <p>Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue mollis interdum.</p>
            </Carousel.Caption>
          </Carousel.Item>
          <Carousel.Item>
            <img
              className="d-block w-100"
              src="holder.js/800x400?text=Second slide&bg=282c34"
              alt="Third slide"
            />

            <Carousel.Caption>
              <h3>Second slide label</h3>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
            </Carousel.Caption>
          </Carousel.Item>
          <Carousel.Item>
            <img
              className="d-block w-100"
              src="holder.js/800x400?text=Third slide&bg=20232a"
              alt="Third slide"
            />

            <Carousel.Caption>
              <h3>Third slide label</h3>
              <p>
                Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur.
              </p>
            </Carousel.Caption>
          </Carousel.Item>
        </Carousel>
      </div>
    )
  }
}


export default ControlledCarousel
```

Does anyone who had ever use next.js framework and react-bootstrap ?
Can you help me how to fix this problem
tks everyone for helping for this issue!

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is due to the version of React you're using. The [Context API](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/03/29/react-v-16-3.html) was introducted in `v16.3.0`. Could you try updating to the newest version of React?